# Adding ":" between two words in stringByAppendingString

Tags: objective-c

I need to add `:` between 2 strings when i add them together.
I couldnt find simple way to do that,and i am sure there is .

```
 NSString *inBase64;
    inBase64=[userName.text stringByAppendingString:idNumber.text];
```

I need: `userName:idNumber`

Thnks

Comment: Use `NSString *inBase64 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", userName.text, idNumber.text];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stringWithFormat...

```
NSString *inBase64 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", userName.text, idNumber.text];
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way. Useful when you have a lot of string parts:

```
NSArray *parts = @[ userName.text, idNumber.text, /* more */ ];
NSString *string = [parts componentsJoinedByString:@":"];
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `stringByAppendingString:` use `stringByAppendingFormat:`, like this:

```
inBase64 = [userName.text stringByAppendingFormat:@":%@", idNumber.text];
```

you can also use the `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` method, like this:

```
inBase64 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", userName.text, idNumber.text];
```